# Why does java parseInt throw an exception here?

Tags: java

Why does this code throw an exception?

```
Integer.parseInt("4949", 2);
```

It shouldn't right?

Comment: `4` isn't a valid digit in base 2, just like `X` isn't a valid digit in base 10.

Comment: @Reimeus - It's _at least_ base 10. E.g., it could also be hex.

Comment: What did you expect to do for invalid input?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're parsing an `int` in base 2.  `4` is not in base 2.  Neither is `9`, for that matter.

Recall the signature for [`parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):  if you specify a radix, then it will attempt to parse the number for that given radix.  If it can't, it should rightfully throw an exception.

Comment: @Thilo:  It doesn't even *get* to 9 - it chokes on `4` first.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 Integer.parseInt("4949", 2)
```

To

```
 Integer.parseInt("4949", 10)
```

The number after the comma is your radix, and if you want a standard decimal, then use 10